# OpenSans Regular font-face IE-11 issue

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, fonts

I have search through many posts on this forum and tried few things as well. But not manage to get it working.

I have font called OpenSans Regular. And applying to the html elements through css file.

My Css:

```
    @font-face {
        font-family: OpenSans-Regular;
        src: url('../../../clientCfgr/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.ttf'),
             url('../../../clientCfgr/fonts/OpenSans-Regular.otf');
    }
```

But for some reason it's not working. I have gone through some MIME type posts as well but not able to work my ways around.

I have other site in which i have a font called LuloOne and for that I have applied the similar font face css.

```
<pre>@font-face {
    font-family: LuloCleanOneBold;
    src: url('../../../clientCfgr/fonts/LuloCleanOneBold.otf');
}
</pre>
```

and this is working fine with IE-11.

I have also read where few users talked about changing some setting in IE. That solution will not work for me either. As I cant approach my users to do that settings in their browser.

Thanks.

Comment: Everything, including IE11, [supports WOFF](http://caniuse.com/#search=woff), so the first step here is to remove all those superfluous formats from your `@font-face`. WOFF is byte-equivalent to `ttf` and `otf`, so remove those, and `eot` hasn't been necessary in IE since IE9, so remove that, too. Now you have no ambiguities in which resource is *actually* getting used.

Comment: I have removed those additional formats. It was like that only. When it was not working I am forced to added those by trying some solutions online. So after removing I am left with .ttf and .otf format. Still dint help.

Comment: no, that's the wrong simplification. Get rid of those two, and instead use WOFF exclusively. Universally installable fonts (ttf/otf) come with all kinds of rejections in IE an other browsers.

Comment: Thanks @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans it works fine now.